# Executing multiple exec() from PHP

Tags: php, apache, exec

Situation:

I have a PHP application where I need to get some output from `exec()` commands.
`exec()` commands are used on different locations throughout the application.

When a user opens multiple pages in the same browser, the `exec()` commands are allways executed sequentially; If a user opens a second page, the second page waits for the `exec()` command of the first page to finish, before executing.
If I open a second page in a different browser, or in incognito, this problem does not occur.

```
Example test code:
$exec = "notepad.exe"
$data = shell_exec($exec);
echo $data;
```

When running this code in the browser, the browser waits for the notepad process to close. When running the script a second time simultaniously, the second notepad process is only started when the first one is closed, unless it's ran from a different browser.

Question:
How can I run multiple `exec()` commands simultaneously from the same browser (in different tabs) while still beeing able to catch the output.

Tested on Apache 2.4 running PHP 5.4.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a combination with the use of sessions as described here:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44942

Solution:
While using sessions, we need to call session_write_close(); before running any exec() command.